# Merge Dataframes based on specific value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I know it might be super easy but I am new to dataframe operations. I have **17** dataframes in total and I need to merge them into a single one. For example:

DF1:

```
| id    | val_1    |
|-------|----------|
| A     |        0 |
| B     |        2 |
| C     |        1 |
```

DF2:

```
| id    | val_2    |
|-------|----------|
| A     |        5 |
| D     |        2 |
```

The desire result should be:

```
| id    | val_1    | val_2    |
|-------|----------|----------|
| A     |        0 |        5 |
| B     |        2 |      N/A |
| C     |        1 |      N/A |
| D     |      N/A |        2 |
```

What should be the correct method to use, `merge` or `concate`?
Thank you!

Comment: Use an OUTER JOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Comment: `result = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='outer')`

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome to upvote the post I've linked you to, if you found it helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['A', 0],
    ['B', 2],
    ['C', 1]]),
    columns=['id', 'val1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['A', 5],
    ['D', 2]]),
    columns=['id', 'val2'])

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='outer'))
```

should give the desired output:

```
  id val1 val2
0  A    0    5
1  B    2  NaN
2  C    1  NaN
3  D  NaN    2
```